# Navigator error in flutter (Drawer button logout)

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a Drawer that i share in all my StatefulWidget like this

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
key: _scaffoldKey,
drawer: SharedDrawer()
... //More code
```

In the Drawer i put a LogOut button that redirect the user to the login page cleaning all the router stack like this.

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

but when i try to log in again to the app this error appears.

> flutter: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe. At this
>   point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable. To
>   safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a
>   reference to the ancestor by calling inheritFromWidgetOfExactType() in
>   the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.

what i'm doing wrong ?

how i can manage the login/out in the app or is something with the navigator stack ?

Regards!

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It might be helpful tha we fully understand your problem. Also, I've found [this post](https://fantashit.com/navigator-error-drawer-button-logout/) with the exact same details of what you've provided. It looks like it was resolved already. Could you confirm it by posting the solution here as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The error "Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe" is usually caused by reusing reference of Widgets that has been disposed previously i.e. during `Navigator.of(context).pop();`

One way to solve this issue is to keep track the context that you're using on your widgets so it won't reuse previoulsy disposed contexts.